# How can I grab data from more than one droppable element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

In my script I'm experimenting with jquery draggable & droppable, [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/184/). I'm trying to grab the data (to eventually put in a database) from each draggable element that's dropped into the droppable div. Right now I have it so that I can only get the data from the div the was last dropped.

```
    $('#sortcard, #dropbox, #dropbox1').droppable({
        accept: '.sorting',
        hoverClass: 'border',
        tolerance: 'touch',
        drop: function(e, ui) {
          $(this).append(ui.draggable.html() + '<br/>');
          $("#add_friend").show().fadeOut(12000);
          $(e.target).droppable("disable");
          $(e.target).append("<input type='button' name='Sub' value='clear'/>").click(function() {
            $(this).empty().droppable("enable");
             });

            var dropbox = $('#dropbox').html();
            var dropbox1 = $('#dropbox1').html();

            if(dropbox && dropbox1 !== '') {
                 $.post("account_main.php", {data: $(this).text()}, function(data) {
                    $('#demo').html(data);
                });     
             }
          }
      });
```

I'm thinking the culprit may be

```
{data: $(this).text()}, function(data) {
    $('#demo').html(data);
});
```

I have toyed with it and still not getting the results I desire. I feel maybe my coding on this is sketchy and needs a makeover, but I just need some ideas to push me in the right direction to make it efficient and would be very appreciative as well of any tips.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: indented your code, way easier to follow this way. :-)

Comment: I have 3 droppable divs and I want to know how to $_GET data from all 3 when a draggable element is dropped into it. As of right now I only $_GET data from the last droppable that was dropped. I want it so when all three are dropped i can $GET data from all 3. You follow? @flackend

Comment: It looks like you are using POST, so $_GET will be empty in your PHP script. When exactly do you want to access the html within the three droppable divs? When two are filled, and then the last div is dropped?

Comment: Yea, I was just using $_GET as an example. I know I'm using $_POST. I want to match the data for each one with the data in my database. You follow? @MatthewBlancarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only getting the data from the last `droppable` because your sending `$(this).text()`.

In that context `$(this)` is the last `droppable` that was dropped. Since you want more than that, you'll want to replace:

```
{data: $(this).text()}
```

with something like:

```
{
    sortcard: $('div#sortcard').text(),
    dropbox: $('div#dropbox').text(),
    dropbox1: $('div#dropbox1').text()
}
```

Which will send the data from those three DIVs.